# Is there any built-in function from Elasticsearch to prevent indexing document on specified condition?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm implementing the multi-tenancy system that use Elasticsearch.
A single index keeps all tenants documents. Because it has the same fields for all tenants.
I have a field to identify the tenant like this.

```
{
  tenantId: "cba1714d-0062-4fc6-a11d-88e062b1fe88"
}
```

The condition is the users in this tenant id should be able to index documents which tenant id == "cba1714d-0062-4fc6-a11d-88e062b1fe88" only.

Is there any built-in function to prevent the crossed tenant indexing document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can achive using [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) in elasticsearch. Ingest pipeline have [drop processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/drop-processor.html) which will drop document based on specific condition.

You can create Ingest pipeline using below command or from Kibana.

```json
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my-pipeline
{
  "description": "My optional pipeline description",
  "processors": [
    {
      "drop": {
        "if": "ctx.tenantId != 'cba1714d-0062-4fc6-a11d-88e062b1fe88'"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

After creating pipeline, you can provide pipeline name in index request:

```json
POST my-index/_doc?pipeline=my-pipeline
{
  "@timestamp": "2099-03-07T11:04:05.000Z",
  "tenantId": "cba1714d-0062-4fc6-a11d-88e062b1fe88"
}
```

If you want to index document based on `tenantId` in diffrent index then you can use  [Set Processor](https://elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/set-processor.html) and change value of `_index` based on condition.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your answer.